# Is it possible to set a style in XAML that selectively affects controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

In `<Window.Resources>` I have defined following style:

```
    <Style x:Key="textBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Style>
```

I have defined some grid where I have four `TextBlocks`:

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">Server</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">IP</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">Port</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">Status</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
```

**Problem:** I need to reference the `textBlockStyle` four times.

**Question:** Is it possible to set that style just once at in `WrapPanel` or somewhere else without repeating the reference to the style?

Maybe something like:

```
    <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">
        <TextBlock>Server</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>IP</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Port</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Status</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
```

**I am not searching for a global solution!** I could delete that `x:Key="textBlockStyle"` property, but that would affect *all* `TextBlocks` in the Window. I need a more selective mechanism, but without that ugly code duplication.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have several options, presented here in order of how well they scale.

**Option 1: Define the Style without a key at a lower level**

You can stick the resource at the `WrapPanel` level so that it only affects controls inside that `WrapPanel`:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>

    <!-- TextBlocks here -->
</WrapPanel>
```

Notice the lack of key. This `Style` will apply to all `TextBlock`s within the `WrapPanel`.

**Option 2: Define the Style with a key and again without at a lower level**

If you define the `Style` at a higher level with a key, you can then define another `Style` at a lower level without a key, and base that `Style` on the higher level one:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="textBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource textBlockStyle"/>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>

        <!-- TextBlocks here -->
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

This results in a `Style` being automatically applied to `TextBlock`s inside the `WrapPanel`, but not outside it. Also, you don't duplicate the details of the `Style` - they are stored at a higher level.

**Option 3: Place the Styles in a ResourceDictionary and selectively merge it**

Finally, you can place your `Style`s in a separate `ResourceDictionary` and selectively merge that dictionary into a control's `Resources` collection:

```
<!-- TextBlockStyles.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- Window.xaml -->
<Window>
    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBlockStyles.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>

<!-- Alternative Window.xaml if you have only one RD to merge in -->
<Window>
    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBlockStyles.xaml"/>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

Now you can have as many style sets defined in separate dictionaries as you like, and then selectively apply them to your element tree.

Comment: I usually prefer option 2 if I have the style already defined and use it elsewhere, otherwise option 1. For what it's worth. Great answer Kent.

Answer (score 2):

yup,you can do that.you almost have the right idea. you do that like this....

```
<WrapPanel>
< WrapPanel. Resources >
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Style>
</WrapPanel.Resources/>
        <TextBlock Server</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >IP</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >Port</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >Status</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
```

by using the {x:type } syntax you dont need the x:key,it will set the style for all textblocks in the wrappanel. if you want diff styles, you can still use the x:key and explicity set the style on the textblock.