# Is "unobtrusive" styling possible in WPF / XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I know I can reuse styles by creating a style like:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```

And applying it:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

However, I would like to specify a style that automatically applies to e.g. all buttons in the user control, like I would have done in CSS with `button { margin: 5px }`. Is this possible?

EDIT: Similar question: [Is it possible to set a style in XAML that selectively affects controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694798/is-it-possible-to-set-a-style-in-xaml-that-selectively-affects-controls?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use what are called "implicit styles" by omitting the `x:Key` attribute and including only the `TargetType`. This will then apply to every control of that type in the scope of the `ResourceDictionary` where it is defined.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

By removing the "x:key" Property in the style, it is inherited to all TargetTypes. Which means the same as in your css example.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```