# How can I change the default style of WPF controls for a single assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a WPF plugin for some off-the-shelf product, and in this plugin I've used a theme/style to change the minimal width of all buttons like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
</Style>
```

In the newest version of said off-the-shelf product they migrated from winforms to WPF themselves. Now when my plugin is loaded the style that previously just affected my plugged-in forms now affects *all* buttons in the application. This renders most UI's unusable.

I know I can use dictionary key based resources to make this style specific to my buttons, but this means I have to change each and every button in my plugin by hand, as well as not forget to set the style of each button in the future (and other elements this problem applies to). There are other options to make the style specific to a set of buttons, as seen in [Is it possible to set a style in XAML that selectively affects controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694798/is-it-possible-to-set-a-style-in-xaml-that-selectively-affects-controls) But I'm looking for a way to let my style affect only those of my plugin (so a bit more coarse than talked about in the referenced question). This plugin consists of multiple windows/views (tied together with Caliburn.Micro).

Is there a way to easily scope a style to for instance an assembly or namespace? I'd really like to define my resources just once. Currently it's defined at the Application.Resources level, if there's one more appropriate I'd like to hear that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set a style in XAML that selectively affects controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694798/is-it-possible-to-set-a-style-in-xaml-that-selectively-affects-controls)

Comment: @Sinatr I've updated my question to highlight why it's different than the one you referenced, thanks for the link though, hadn't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

With a `ResourceDictionary`, we can set default style wich will be applied without define style in Xaml.

**DictionayNew.xaml :**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
                xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- default button -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
    </Style>

    <!-- new button style --> 
    <Style x:Key="ActionButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    </Style>

    <!-- new button style based on previous style -->
    <Style x:Key="BigActionButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ActionButton}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your Xaml, use the dictionary :

```
<Window x:Class="CheckDoublonImageBing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="DictionaryNew.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then, use `Button` as usual or with new style

```
<Button Content="Refresh" />
<Button Content="Delete selected" Style="{DynamicResource ActionButton}" />
```

With no style defined, button will have default style defined in the dictionary.

**EDIT :**
You can set merged dictionary by code like this :

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("DictionayNew.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Comment: I don't actually define my own window, I use Caliburn.Micro's IWindowManager for that which loads one of several UserControls as it's main content. I'm looking for a way to define the button style once. Your answers helps me avoid having to define the style on each button, but I still need to define it in each of my UserControl's ResourceDictionary. Do you know of a way to apply a style to a whole assembly or namespace?

Comment: @dvdvorle see my edit, I added a way to merged dictionary by code

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify a Key for your Style and apply the Style to all your Buttons.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
</Style>


<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

Without a Key the Style is used for all Buttons in the application (as you have already noticed).

Comment: I found this out by myself, and I actually talked about this type of solution in the question and how it is not appropriate for my problem. Is there a way to scope styles other than using Keys?